# Fourier transform and Zero Order Hold

Tags: fourier-transform, digital-filters, analog-to-digital

I was asked to explain why a zero order hold (ZOH) filter is not a good choice for signal reconstruction.

To answer this question, I was thinking about studying the Fourier transform of the reconstructed signal.

If $x$ is the sampled signal, $\tilde{x}$ its Fourier transform, and $s$ the signal to be reconstructed, we have:

$$ \tilde{s} = \operatorname{sinc}(\pi \nu T)e^{-i\pi\nu T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\tilde{x}(\nu-\frac{k}{T}) $$

I think this is the correct answer (looking for example at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731450/fourier-transform-of-sampling-function)).

But from here, how can I conclude that the ZOH is not good enough to reconstruct the signal ?

How does the $\operatorname{sinc}(\cdot)$ impacts the reconstructed signal ?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: ZOH is what you are stuck with in a conventional DAC that holds the voltage over the sampling period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sinc is relatively poor lowpass filter.

The sum in your equation represents an infinite repetition of the original spectrum. Ideally you only want the spectrum for $k=0$ and the other ones to be gone.

That's typically accomplished with a proper low-pass filter and the sinc doesn't do particularly well here. Example: if you sample at 48 kHz and your original bandwidth is 20 kHz, the first mirror spectrum starts at 28kHz.

The sinc is already down by about 2.5dB at 20 kHz, so it rolls off your passband (which you often need to correct for). However at 28 kHz, it's only down by about 5.5dB so it does a very poor job rejection the first mirror image.

For some application that matters, for other it doesn't.